# turn on/off gps without shownig icon in status bar

Tags: android

In my android application, I succeed with turning on/off gps dynamically whenever required. But I am struggling with hide the gps icon in status bar when turn on gps. How can I do it?

NOTE: I also succeed with hiding whole status bar by making full screen. But I want to hide only gps icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. The status bar icon is controlled by the system and it will not allow third party apps to hide it when GPS is on. This is for security reasons as well. Any rogue app could secretly perform malicious operations using the user's location without the user knowing about it if s/he has no indication that GPS is active.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you hide GPS icon?

I think this is a bad idea, since users want to know whether their GPS is active or not.

This would allows applications to snoop users position without them being aware of that fact, which is NOT a good practise. And this is why your app requires a permission to access phone location.

Comment: The reason behind is that the user always turn off gps due to battery drainage problem. So I want to turn on/off only whenever required and also it must be unknowledgable to him.

Comment: If the user wants its GPS inactive, you should not do it without his/her permission. You can use other location providers, even though they are less precise.

Comment: Is it possible to track location using network provider in not reachable area(i.e. no tower access in mobile). If not, then what is the solution?

Comment: You may show a popup or a message asking for the user to activate GPS because your app needs location. It's the best way I think. Always be truthful with users, they'll appreciate it. If an app were to behave uncontrolled, I'd rather uninstall it ;)

Comment: but it must be unknowledgable to user.

Comment: Why do you absolutely need the user not knowing that his/her phone has GPS activated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24879/discussion-between-antony-paul-raj-and-romain-sertelon)

Answer (score 0):

if you have sdk source file, it's easy:

modify NotificationManagerService.java
in methed enqueueNotificationInternal, add a flag (db file or create a file in /data/) ,when the gps application try to send notification, block it(refer to the packagename).

but if you do not have one ....

sorry ,i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I too got same problem, means when I am asking for gps to give location updates then it will show that gps icon, so if you remove those updates calling like **locationmanager.removeupdates(locationListener)**, then it will remove that gps icon in status bar